# Change string within Brackets with non_greedy pattern

Tags: command-line, text-processing, regex

I am trying to change the string within `()`, and following a non-greedy pattern.

Input:

```
this is 1(the house owner 2(pet-name john james) john and his friend 3(unknown name james) james fred)
```

Output:

```
this is 1(the house owner 2(pet-name xxx-john xxx-james) john and his friend 3(unknown name xxx-james) james fred).
```

The names only within the smallest `()` is matched with `john` or `james` and substituted with non-greedy pattern.

I tried with perl, but failed to get desired output.

Comment: I am not seeing any clear resemblance with your input and output. Could you please elaborate or perhaps add another clear example?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I have updated the input line now. Actually I am trying to replace the names john or  james, with xxx-john or xxx-james, only when the names reside within the smallest brackets. I do not want to change them if they are not within the smallest bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the strings you're working with are as simple as the sample input and output, I'd say you're making this harder than it is. You can just search for "john)" and "james)", like so:

```
$ echo "this is 1(the house owner 2(pet-name john) john and his friend 3(unknown name james) james fred)" | sed -r 's/(john\)|james\))/xxx-\1/g'
this is 1(the house owner 2(pet-name xxx-john) john and his friend 3(unknown name xxx-james) james fred)
```

Since you mentioned non-greedy patterns, I have a feeling there is more to this than your example shows. So, let's pretend we don't know if there will be a closing parenthesis right after the names:

```
$ echo "this is 1(the house owner 2(pet-name john ok) john and his friend 3(unknown name james test) james fred)" | sed -r 's/(\([^()]*)(john|james)([^()]*\))/\1xxx-\2\3/g'
this is 1(the house owner 2(pet-name xxx-john ok) john and his friend 3(unknown name xxx-james test) james fred)
```

The first set of parentheses captures everything after (and including) a literal opening parenthesis *that isn't an opening or closing parenthesis* until it hits "james" or "john".

The second set of parentheses captures "john" or "james".

The third set of parentheses captures anything after "james" or "john" *that isn't an opening or closing parenthesis* until it hits a literal closing parenthesis.

This is a global replacement, so it will work no matter how many sets of parentheses you have. You can even nest them deeper, and this will only apply to the smallest set.

Greediness doesn't come into play in this situation, but if it does for the project you're working on, just add a question mark (e.g. * becomes *?) to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Hi Dynamic,thanks a lot for your response. It works well, but does not replace fully the contents within bracket, if changed slightly. for example, if input has john & james in same bracket : $ echo "this is 1(the house owner 2(pet-name john james ok) john and his friend 3(unknown name james test) james fred)" | sed -r 's/(\([^()]*)(john|james)([^()]*\))/\1xxx-\2\3/g'

Comment: it gives output as :
this is 1(the house owner 2(pet-name john xxx-james ok) john and his friend 3(unknown name xxx-james test) james fred). "john" in brackets stays unchanged.

Comment: You've changed your example input and output two times now. I feel like you're leaving out important details. Please give more than one example for the input string.